# gcc invalid command-line options

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

While compiling with this makefile in gcc I received the error

```
cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files"
```

Now I guess that it has something to do with trying to compile the same file twice but I do not know how.

```
assembler : main.o assembler.o utils.o
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic -lm main.o assembler.o utils.o -o assembler
main.o : main.c assembler.h utils.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic -lm main.c assembler.h utils.h -o main.o
assembler.o : assembler.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic -lm assembler.c -o assembler.o
utils.o : utils.c structs.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic -lm utils.c structs.h -o utils.o
```

Files are includes like this:

```
structs.h is included in utils.c,
utils.c is included in utils.h,
utils.h is included in assembler.c,
assembler.c is included in assembler.h,
assembler.h is included in main.c.
```

(: don't know why, it made me do it in code formation...

Comment: Specifying multiple source files only makes sense if the linker will be invoked.

Comment: you don't "compile" headers, get them out of the compil command, but they indeed are dependancies

Comment: BTW : _utils.c is included in utils.h_ and _assembler.c is included in assembler.h_ doesn't really make sense. .h files are included into .c files but not the other way round.

Comment: Thank you very much, but now occured another problem: I have "undefined reference to 'pow'" and I did add -lm to link the math library. How is that solved?

Comment: @matyah: Put the `-lm` at the end of the command line, or at least after the source or object file that needs it.

Comment: @EOF: "*Specifying multiple source files only makes sense if the linker will be invoked.*" -- You can do, for example, `gcc -c foo.c bar.c`, and it will generate `foo.o` and `bar.o`. But it's no better than compiling them separately (which is what you'll probably do if you're using a Makefile).

Comment: There's no point in compiling headers, only implementation files should be compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probbaly need this makefile (simply remove .h files from the gcc commands):

```
assembler : main.o assembler.o utils.o
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic -lm main.o assembler.o utils.o -o assembler

main.o : main.c assembler.h utils.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic main.c -o main.o

assembler.o : assembler.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic assembler.c -o assembler.o

utils.o : utils.c structs.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic utils.c -o utils.o
```

Comment: Should not include "-lm" or "-o main.o" on the line that compiles main.c, and similar for the assembler.c and utils.c  lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile is incorrectly adding all the dependencies to the compile command, instead of just the first one. The result is that you are trying to compile header files as translation units, which is not appropriate.

It is correct to add all dependencies in the *link* command, which combines multiple object files into an executable. But, as the error message indicates, when creating an object file with the `-c` option, providing more than one source file won't work.

So the compilation recipes will typically use `$<` (first dependency), while the link recipe will use `$^` (all dependencies). See the [automatic variables chapter](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) of the make manual.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better way:

```
assembler:: main.o assembler.o utils.o
    gcc -o $@ main.o assembler.o utils.o -lm
.c.o:
    gcc -c  -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic $*.c
```